# Should we merge [ethics] and [morality]?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, tag-synonyms

The [ethics](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ethics) tag has ten questions and the [morality](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/morality) tag has nine. The tag wiki excerpts on both are basically dictionary definitions. Should we merge these tags?

The [morality](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/morality) tag has a full tag wiki which contains a bit of information on what sort of questions would be appropriate for this site. The [ethics](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ethics) tag has no tag wiki (only an excerpt). I suggest making [ethics](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ethics) a synonym of [morality](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/morality).

Comment: One of the [tag:ethics] questions just got deleted. Now each tag has nine questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

[ethics](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ethics) has now been merged and synonymised with [morality](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/morality). All questions previously tagged with [ethics](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ethics) are now tagged with [morality](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/morality) instead, and [ethics](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ethics) will map to [morality](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/morality) for all new questions.

[Link to synonym.](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/tags/morality/synonyms)

Comment: IMO, the [tag:good-against-evil] tag should NOT be merged with these, since it's about the SFF trope of good-vs-evil whereas the [tag:ethics]/[tag:morality] tags are about the ideas of ethics/morality.